# Jasper reports integration with spring roo not working

Tags: jasper-reports, spring-roo

I am trying to integrate jasper reports with Spring roo. when i run 'osgi start --url http://s.digitalface.ca/jasperoo-latest' in roo shell, will get 'org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle ca.digitalface.jasperoo [77]: Unable to resolve 77.0: missing requirement [77.0] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.springframework.roo.support.style)(version>=1.1.0))' , please help me with this, i am new to spring roo and jasper reports. i have removed old addon of ca.digitalface.jasperoo, still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gvNIX includes JasperReports integration by default. Try it http://code.google.com/p/gvnix/wiki/DocReport

Comment: but i am getting this error....roo> addon install bundle --bundleSymbolicName org.gvnix.web.report.roo.addon
Could not find specified bundle with symbolic name: org.gvnix.web.report.roo.addon

Comment: i was using roo 1.2.3, when i switched to roo 1.2.0 my problem solved.But 'jasperoo setup' command not found in roo shell and when i run 'osgi ps' command it showing that jasperoo is active ([  72] [Active     ] [    1] DigitalFace - jasperoo (0.1.5.RELEASE)).help me